# Why does this PHP mysqli_query () not work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I connected to the database, and it successfully displays `cont` where `id` is `message` (second paragraph of code), so I reckon the first `mysqli_query()` (the one that says `UPDATE`) is not working.

I want the user to type text in `$_POST['message']` (which is also working perfectly, as I've tried in another snippet of code) and display it.

The text is sent to the same PHP page where the form is located. However, I only see what was already in the cell as a placeholder. Any help is appreciated.

```
$message = stripslashes ($_POST ['message']);
mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont=$message WHERE id='message'");

$done = 0;
$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM edit");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
    if ($row["id"] == "message" && $done == 0)
    {
        echo $row["cont"];
        $done = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes arounnd `$message`

Comment: Thank you. I'm not very lucid today. Yes, I do implement error handling in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have correct connection in $con.
You also need to enclose $message in single quotation since it's a string.

```
mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$message' WHERE id='message'");
```

Quite value of **id** you got there. Is that for testing purposes only?

Comment: Yes, it is for testing purposes. I shall tidy up my code when I get this WYSIWYG editor I am trying to write up and running.

Comment: Indeed. I could not accept your answer yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`stripslashes()` is not adequate from a security perspective. Nor is any sort of query where you interpolate values into the SQL. Try a prepared statement instead...

```
$id = 'message';
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE edit SET cont = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['message'], $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure database connection $con. It must be correct and use "mysqli_error()" function like this :

```
<?php 

$message = stripslashes ($_POST ['message']);
mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='".$message."' WHERE id='message'") or  die(mysqli_error($con));

?>
```